# How to get GuestCartId using rest API?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, rest-api, magento2.4

I'm trying to fetch the estimated shipping method, but I can't find it.
How can I get this element for the API code?

Api Url

```
{{Base API URL}}/guest-carts/{{GuestCartId}}/estimate-shipping-methods
```

Comment: can you specify your requirement in some more details what you are looking for??

Comment: I'm trying to get the estimated price of the methods

Answer (score 1):

1. At first, to understand the flow let us start from the beginning. Such as the request from the Network. As you can see the call is a **rest API**. In Magento 2, the rest API calls will be listed in **webapi.xml** on the respective modules.[image]
2. The guest carts estimate shipping method can be found on the file **vendor/magento/module-quote/etc/webapi.xml**.[image]
3. You will find the **route** element in the above-mentioned file for **estimate-shipping-methods** as shown below. In which, the service class is an interface that should be implemented by one class. In our case, it is **vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/GuestCart/GuestShippingMethodManagement.php** and you can find the initial method as mentioned in-service class i.e **estimateByExtendedAddress** in the mentioned PHP file. Whatever this method returns is the response of this API call. [image][image]
4. Hereafter, you can use X-debug or any other debugging technique to understand the flow of code and change the result as you want. You may find events to add observers for it. As APIs are [service contracts](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-contracts.html), Please go through the [extension attributes](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html#extension) if you want to add something.
5. **Additional Point:** As you may have seen many times in the constructor the interface is called whereas an interface doesn't have the ability to change into an object. The object is an instance of the class. So, when an interface is called and it converts to an object in Magento 2. The possible way to achieve this is by adding a preference to send an implemented class when the interface is called. So when the same interface is used in more than one class always check di.xml once to reach the exact file. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get current cart Id using this code.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
) {
    $this->_cart = $cart;
}

public function MyCustomFunction(){
    return $this->_cart->getQuote()->getId();
}
```

Comment: it is showing an error. Could you pass the full code?

Comment: Kindly check you implement the code properly and share the code which you try and what error it show to you.

Comment: shared my code.

Comment: you need to implement the code into the block or helper file and then call that one.

Comment: I tried to use it, but unfortunately it only works if the user accesses the checkout for the first time. I need to make the cart id even if the user doesn't access the cart.

Answer (score 0):

the code i tried

```
<?php

namespace Module\Method\Controller\Index;

class Methodsmodule extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart){
        $this->_cart = $cart;
    }
    
    public function execute(){
        return $this->_cart->getQuote()->getId();
    }

   
}
```